# C++ template specialization for a single method for complex types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have an abstract class and subclass like this:

```
class MyAbstractClass {
public:
    virtual bool shouldDoIt() = 0;
}

template <class T> class MyClass : public MyAbstractClass {
public:

    bool shouldDoIt() { return state; }

private: // assume there are appropriate accessors for these private fields
    bool state;
    T val;
}
```

This implementation of `shouldDoIt()` is fine for most types. But if `T` happens to be a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass<X>>>`, where `X` can be any type, then I want the implementation to be something like this:

```
bool shouldDoIt() {
    if(state) return true;
    for(auto &member : val) {
        if(member->state) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of if it's a `std::unordered_map<X, std::shared_ptr<MyClass<Y>>`, where `X` and `Y` can be any types, I want this implementation:

```
bool shouldDoIt() {
    if(state) return true;
    for(auto &member : val) {
        if(member.second->state) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I specialize the implementation of shouldDoIt() for these types? I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options for doing this, and which one I would choose depends on how much I want this special behavior to be customizable. With what you showed here, I'd probably use an overloaded function:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass : public MyAbstractClass {
public:

    bool shouldDoIt() {
        if (state) return true;
        return specializedShouldDoIt(val);
    }

private:
    template <class U>
    static bool specializedShouldDoIt(U&) { return false; }

    template <class X>
    static bool specializedShouldDoIt(
                        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass<X>>> &val) {
        // your loop is equivalent to std::any_of
        return std::any_of(val.begin(), val.end(), [](auto &member) {
            return member->state;
        });
    }

    template <class X, class Y>
    static bool specializedShouldDoIt(
                   std::unordered_map<X, std::shared_ptr<MyClass<Y>>> &val) {
        return std::any_of(val.begin(), val.end(), [](auto &member) {
            return member.second->state;
        });
    }
};
```

---

The other alternative I might consider is having an external helper class, so that I could use partial specialization:

```
template <class T>
struct PerformShouldDoIt
{
    static bool shouldDoIt(bool state, T&) { return state; }
};

template <class X>
struct PerformShouldDoIt<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass<X>>>>
{
    static bool shouldDoIt(bool state,
                           std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass<X>>>& val) {
        return std::any_of(val.begin(), val.end(), [](auto &member) {
            return member->state;
        });
    }
};

// Similarly for whatever you wanted to specialize for

...

template <class T>
class MyClass : public MyAbstractClass {
public:

    bool shouldDoIt() {
        return PerformShouldDoIt<T>::shouldDoIt(state, val);
    }
};
```

Comment: I ended up using your first suggestion, which worked. Minor typo: `return specializedShouldDoIt(member);` -> `return specializedShouldDoIt(val);`